# How can I increase or decrease a circle

Tags: c#, winforms, drawing

I draw a circle on `Load` event and I have two buttons to increase and decrease the size of the circle. But I can't shrink or enlarge the size along the center of the circle.

```
private Draw draw = new Draw();
private int width = 150;
private int height = 150;
private int xLocation = 300;
private int yLocation = 100;

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
}

protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
{
    draw.circle(xLocation, yLocation, width, height, e.Graphics);
}

private void enlarge_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    width = width + 5;
    height = height + 5;
    draw.circle(xLocation, yLocation, width, height, this.CreateGraphics());
}

private void Shrink_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    width = width - 5;
    height = height - 5;
    draw.circle(xLocation, yLocation, height, height, this.CreateGraphics());
} 

internal class Draw
{
    public int x { get; set; }
    public int y { get; set; }
    public int width { get; set; }
    public int height { get; set; }
    public Graphics g { get; set; }

    public void circle(int x, int y, int width, int height, Graphics g)
    {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
        Pen color = new Pen(Color.Red);
        this.g = g;
        g.Clear(Color.White);
        Rectangle circle = new Rectangle(x, y, width, height);
        g.DrawEllipse(color, circle);
        g.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you want centered circle? Then you also have to change location, e.g. for x: `width-=2;xLocation+=2;`

Comment: Try to call method *this.Invalidate()* after calling *draw.circle* in the shrink and enlarge button handlers. Also remove *g.Dispose()* in the *cicrle* method. We do not want to dispose graphics because we will reuse it on subsequent drawings.

Comment: _this.CreateGraphics()_ . Winforms graphics basic rule #1 : 

Never use `control.CreateGraphics`! Never try to cache a `Graphics` object! Either draw into a `Bitmap bmp` using a `Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp)` or in the `Paint` event of a control, using the `e.Graphics` parameter.. - So your code needs a lot of changes to get a persistent result. (You can test the persistance of your graphics by doing a Minimize/Maximize sequence..) - As for the circle: You will simply need to calculate the top left corner correctly!

Answer (score 1):

Use [Rectangle.Inflate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.rectangle.inflate?view=netcore-3.1) method to enlarge or reduce a `Rectangle` in both directions a long an axis.

You can replace the `width`, `height`, `xLocation`, and `yLocation` class members with a single variable of `Rectangle` type and instantiate it in the Form's `Load` event:

```cs
private Rectangle drawRect;

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Set the default size and location...
    drawRect = new Rectangle(
        (ClientRectangle.Width - 150) / 2,
        (ClientRectangle.Height - 150) / 2, 150, 150);
}
```

If you need to reposition the drawing rectangle when the `Form` resizes, handle the `Resize` event as follows:

```cs
private void Form1_Resize(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Assuming you want to center the drawing rectangle...
    drawRect = new Rectangle(
        (ClientRectangle.Width - drawRect.Width) / 2,
        (ClientRectangle.Height - drawRect.Height) / 2,
        drawRect.Width, drawRect.Height);
}
```

To enlarge and reduce the size:

```cs
private void enlarge_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var cr = ClientRectangle;
    cr.Inflate(-50, -50);

    //Optional check to draw within the ClientRectangle with some margins
    if (cr.Contains(drawRect))
    {
        drawRect.Inflate(5, 5);
        Invalidate();
    }
}

private void Shrink_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Optional check to have a minimum size for the Rectangle.
    if (drawRect.Width >= 15 && drawRect.Height >= 15)
    {
        drawRect.Inflate(-5, -5);
        Invalidate();
    }
}
```

The `Draw` class can be simplified to:

```cs
internal class Draw
{
    public static void Circle(Graphics g, int x, int y, int width, int height) =>
        Circle(g, new Rectangle(x, y, width, height));

    public static void Circle(Graphics g, Rectangle rect)
    {
        g.Clear(Color.White);
        g.DrawEllipse(Pens.Red, rect);
    }
}
```

So you can call the static methods in any `Paint` event as simple as this:

```cs
private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e) =>
    Draw.Circle(e.Graphics, drawRect);
```

**Side Note:**

- Call the [Control.Invalidate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.invalidate?view=netcore-3.1) method to notify the drawing canvas (the `Form` in your case) to refresh the drawings/painting routine and avoid the redundant calls.
- No reason to create new `Graphics` objects in this context.
- The `Pen` is also a disposable object and should be disposed. Use to create the disposable objects in [using](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-statement) blocks to do that for you.